# Android - How can I generate a random color with limits?

Tags: android, view, random, colors, draw

Well, I'm trying to generate a color randomly, but with limits.

By making the RGB colors only between 0 and 49.

It is supposed to make it like this: color.nextInt(50); Right?

This is the code from the activity that draws the squares:

```
public class Draw extends View 
{
    public Draw(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
    }

    Paint prop = new Paint();
    Random color = new Random();

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        int oriwidth = 0;
        int oriheight = 0;      

        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) 
        {
            int red = color.nextInt(50);
            int green = color.nextInt(50);
            int blue = color.nextInt(50);

            prop.setARGB(0, red, green, blue);
            canvas.drawRect(oriwidth += 10, oriheight += 10, width -= 10, height -= 10, prop);
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is a full square in white. Without the limit I get it good.

Can you make me get it right to draw a square between a set of values?

Thanks for the help, and sorry for the english.

Comment: Is there a reason you set the alpha to 0(invisible)?

Comment: Really? It works without the limit... It now works... Just have set it to 255. I'm really stupid :P Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First param at setArgb is transparency. You should always set it to 255.

Comment: Well I didn't think it was that, because after I set the limit it worked (and alpha was on 0)... I'm so stupid -.-' It now works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why you are confined to 50, as the highest limit is 255  .

```
int min = 0;
int max = 255;
int transparency=255;// from 0 to 255 ,255 means no transparency

Random r = new Random();
int red = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
int green= r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
int blue= r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
prop.setARGB(transparency, red, green, blue);
```

By changing min ,max you can limit the color combination.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in comments, you need to set the alpha transparency for it to show.

The reason it worked "without the limits" is because you were overflowing the range `0...255` for each component. `nextInt()` with no argument generates a number from `0...MAX_INT-1`.

To see why that matters, check out the source of [`Paint#setARGB()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/graphics/Paint.java):

```
public void setARGB(int a, int r, int g, int b) {
    setColor((a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b);
}
```

All it's doing is shifting and combining values into one "packed" `int`. If you step outside the range of one byte per component, the behavior is "undefined". For example, if you try to define a color as `ARGB = 0,256,0,0`, you get this:

```
(a << 24) = 0
(r << 16) = 16777216
(g <<  8) = 0
(b)       = 0
(final)   = 16777216
```

Now if you unpack that to components, you can see the issue. `16777216 >> 24 = 1`, so it gets that for the alpha and all the rest are zeroed. So effectively, you now have a color `ARGB = 1,0,0,0`

---

Basically, you *were* assigning an alpha when you ran it "without limits", but it was completely unintentional. Remember to limit your components to a max of 255, even if you are explicitly assigning an alpha, or you may end up with unexpected results.